# I can't fetch time and destinations from bart.gov XML using JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, api, google-maps

well i'm working a website where i'm using google maps to simulate the famous bart BAY AREA RAPID TRANSIT routes ...i made a java script which has all my functions  and used it in my "index.php" ..and made another "connection.php" file which creates the cUrl session to fetch the bart webpage for info and it looks like this :

```
<?php

$site = "http://api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=RICH&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V";

$ch = curl_init($site); // Initialize a cURL session

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $xml;
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

and this is the function i'm using to get the needed data from bart's xml file:

```
function getTimes(marker, station, name, infowindow){
alert(station);
var times = [];
jQuery.get("connection.php", {}, function (data){
    $(data).find("station").each(function (){
         var $each = jQuery(this);
         var abrv = $each.find("abbr").text();

         if(station == abrv){                
             $each.find("etd").each(function (){
                 var that = jQuery(this);
                 var destino = that.find("destination").text();
                 var time = that.find("estimate").text();
                 alert(destino);
                 alert(times);
                 times.push(time);
                 destinos.push(destino);
                 infowindow.setContent(time + destino);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);                     
             });
             var contentString ='<h2>' + name + '</h2>';
             for(var i = 0; i < times.length; i++){
                contentString += '<tr>  <td>' + times[i] + ' </td><td> ' + destinos[i] + '</td></tr></br></br>'

             }
             infowindow.setContent(contentString);
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }

    });
});
```

}

UNFORTUNATELY IT DISPLAYS THE STATION ABBREVIATION OF THE STATION ONLY , it doesn't display the estimate and destinations ..what is wrong ? i guess i've implemented everything as it should be !

Comment: If you had implemented everything as it should be, I wouldn't be typing this in :)  It would help if you'd post at least some of the XML. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: @Pointy i said i "GUESS" lol ...anyway this is how the xml looks like , http://api.bart.gov/docs/etd/etd.aspx  :)

Comment: When I try and parse the XML via the jQuery API, I get an error; I don't know why. Do you see console errors?

Comment: @Pointy i've checked it and it has this warning vent.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.  , what would be this ? :)

Comment: @Pointy the previous post was from chrome's ,but through Mozilla it  showed this: The character encoding of HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser config if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. BART%20GOOGLE%20MAPS
18:25:22.808 Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. BART%20GOOGLE%20MAPS
18:25:37.942 Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. jquery.min.js:16

Comment: I don't know; that doesn't look related to this problem. I've gotten the XML to parse and it works, though your code that tries to get the "time" doesn't work properly because the `<estimate>` tag contains a whole bunch of sub-tags; you're just pulling the combined text. [Here is the (somewhat) working jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/ukuMeJUy/2/edit)